# Android Neural Network InvalidClassException

Tags: java, android, neural-network

I have been writing an android app using neural network (NeuroPh Framework).
I have got my network ready and saved , and then i ported it into the application.
The present library configuration which i am using in the app is

1. encog-engine-2.5.0.jar
2. JOCL-0.1.3a-beta.jar
3. neuroph.jar

The code of line where i load my network

```
        // R.raw.imsafe is the neural network
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.imsafe);

        // load neural network
        NeuralNetwork nnet = NeuralNetwork.load(is);
```

i am getting this exception

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork; 
Incompatible class (SUID): org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork: 
static final long serialVersionUID =5L; 
but expected org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork: 
static final long serialVersionUID =4L;
```

Is it cause of library version??

I used NeuroPh Studio 2.7 to develop the network.

Comment: Have you defined a `serialVersionUID` manually in your class ?

Comment: No.. Nowhere i have defined the `serialVersionUID` ..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!.. I was using an older neuroph library.. upgraded it to the latest 2.7 [NeuroPh 2.7](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neuroph/?source=dlp) and ran into a new Exception!

Answer (score 0):

serialVersionUID is mentioned in the ImageNeuralData class in package org.encog.ml.data.image\

Check if you already have this class in the build.